# How to handle a timeout

Tags: python, python-requests, authorize.net

I have an application using authorize.net, and we seem to have connection issues from time to time.

I don't think that the response is ever returned here.

```
response = createtransactioncontroller.getresponse()
```

When looking at the code for the authorizenet library, I noticed that the timeout is not being set.

```
self._httpResponse = requests.post(self.endpoint, data=xmlRequest, headers=constants.headers, proxies=proxyDictionary)
```

If that's the case, how should I handle the case that the response never gets returned?  It seems like a hack to add a timeout to the authorizenet library because it is used outside the scope of my project, but it also doesn't seem like best practice to add my own timer.  What solution would you recommend?

Comment: Their code is open source. Fork their code, make this change, and make a pull request. Then everyone benefits from your change.